# jquery on("change" vs on("input" - trying to unify behaviour on IE vs FF vs Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm trying to slide a HTML5 range slider, and update the text in a div to whatever value the slider takes. I have noticed that IE and Firefox+Chrome interpret HTML5 range events differently for jquery's `on("change"` vs `on("input"`

On Linux and Windows, Firefox+Chrome both wait for mouse release for `on("change"`, and fire immediately for `on("input"`.
On Windows, IE fires immediately on `on("change"`, and doesn't do anything for `on("input` (i.e. it doesn't work)

I've tested this on FF36, Chrome40, IE11.

Try this out at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f831muxb/), on different browsers, replacing `change` with `input`.

My question: Is there a way I can make all browsers update immediately, as the slider is being moved? Do I have to write separate code to check what browser I'm in before calling a variant of the `.on(` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use both bindings at once?

```
$(document).on('input change', sliderSelector, function () {
    alert('TA-DA-DA-DAAA!');
});
```

Comment: Holy Moly! I did not know that you could stack inputs like that! Going to run off and read about it now...

Answer (score 1):

You can bind both events.

```
$(element).on("input change", eventHandler);
```